# Syntax error for UPDATE Table

Tags: java, mysql

It's since 2 hours that I am working with an UPDATE TABLE statement which gives me always Syntax error. I made this:

```
String falseValue = "False";
String emptyValue = "";
try {
        OrderListViewerModel orderlistviewermodell = (OrderListViewerModel) tableOrder.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TABLE productList SET ordered = '" + falseValue + "', orderedshopphone = '" + emptyValue + "' WHERE barcode = " + orderlistviewermodell.getProductBarcode() + "");
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM orderList WHERE productbarcode=?");
        pst.setString(1, orderlistviewermodell.getProductBarcode());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        pst.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StoreListViewerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The Delete Works fine but the update not really. It says I have Syntax Error and check it out.

Comment: You already use PrepapredStatement why you don't use the `?` to avoid SQL Injection, or syntax injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update query has `TABLE` that no needed.

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE productList SET ordered = '" + falseValue + "', orderedshopphone = '" + emptyValue + "' WHERE barcode = " + orderlistviewermodell.getProductBarcode() + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

the basic syntax of update query is

```
update table_name set col1 = val1 , col2 = val2 ,... [where condition];
```

so there is no need of  **TABLE** key word.

your line should be

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE productList SET ordered = '" + falseValue + "', orderedshopphone = '" + emptyValue + "' WHERE barcode = " + orderlistviewermodell.getProductBarcode() + "");
```